# pass string value

Tags: apex, http

In the Below requeststring, I have to pass one value from the post form data.

For e.g: I have a user name text box and I need to pass that user name value on form submission in the below request string:

```
String abc = post data from form;


String requestString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <bns:EnvironmentExtensions xmlns:bns="http://api.platform.boomi.com/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" extensionGroupId="" environmentId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"> <bns:connections> <bns:connection name="SFDC connection" id="XXXX"> <bns:field componentOverride="false" usesEncryption="false" encryptedValueSet="false" value= ***abc*** id="user"/> <bns:field componentOverride="false" usesEncryption="true" encryptedValueSet="true" id="password" value="password"/> </bns:connection> </bns:connections> </bns:EnvironmentExtensions>';
```

i have tried \'+abc+\' but it pass as abc in the HTTPRequest body, it does pass the value assigned to abc string.

I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to escape the quote characters, because then they become part of the string itself (so you'd be sending `'+abc+'` instead of the contents of abc).

```
String requestString = 
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <bns:Environment'+
    'Extensions xmlns:bns="http://api.platform.boomi.com/" xmlns:xsi="http://'+
    'www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" extensionGroup'+
    'Id="" environmentId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"> <bns:connections> <bns:connection'+
    ' name="SFDC connection" id="XXXX"> <bns:field componentOverride="false" '+
    'usesEncryption="false" encryptedValueSet="false" value="'+abc+'" id="use'+ // abc here
    'r"/> <bns:field componentOverride="false" usesEncryption="true" encrypte'+
    'dValueSet="true" id="password" value="password"/> </bns:connection> </bn'+
    's:connections> </bns:EnvironmentExtensions>';
```

Note: I just word wrapped this for legibility using a simple regex replace in my text editor: `(.{1,72})` -> `'\1'+`.

Notice how the `+abc+` is a black color as opposed to the brown color used for string literals.

In reality, I would strongly consider using [Dom.Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm) to build an XML this complex, because you also need to remember that some characters may need to be encoded in a special manner to avoid breaking the XML/your service. For example, if the original value were to contain a quotation mark (`"`), your service might interpret the XML incorrectly (as it should, because XML does not allow quotation marks inside an attribute value).

Answer (score 0):

it works here is the solution:

string strCon1 = "hello this is the string";
string body = strCon1 + post form data +" last part of the string";